# Elasticsearch NumberFormatException when sorting by numeric and date fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am attempting to sort on two fields, one is a date field the other is an integer field. I have verified that the fields are mapped correctly and that the values for all of the indexed documents have the correct data types, however every time i try to sort by the numeric field I ES returns an exception [java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)].

The wierd thing is that it returns results and they seem to be sorted correctly so I'm not entirely sure what effect this is having but I know I should not have any errors in the response.

Here is a the mapping:

```
{
   "blcdt.products": {
      "mappings": {
         "review_143758": {
            "properties": {
               "date_reviewed": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "YYYY-MM-dd"
               },
               "description": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "manufacturer": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "model_number": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "boost": 2,
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "norms": {
                     "enabled": true
                  }
               },
               "msrp": {
                  "type": "float"
               },
               "product": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "product_name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "boost": 2,
                  "fields": {
                     "full": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "boost": 4,
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "norms": {
                           "enabled": true
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               "product_type": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "review_category": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "review_title": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "review_type": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "review_type_priority": {
                  "type": "integer"
               },
               "score": {
                  "type": "float"
               },

            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is a query that throws the exception:

```
POST /blcdt.products/review_143758/_search?pretty=true
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "review_category": "Game Reviews"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "from": 0,
   "size": 8,
   "sort": [
      {
         "review_type_priority": {
            "order": "desc"
         }
      },
      {
         "date_reviewed": {
            "order": "desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "fields": [
      "review_title",
      "review_type",
      "score"
   ]
}
```

and here is the abbreviated response from ES:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 4,
      "failures": [
         {
            "index": "blcdt.products",
            "shard": 2,
            "status": 500,
            "reason": "QueryPhaseExecutionException[[blcdt.products][2]: query[filtered(ConstantScore(cache(review_category:Game Reviews)))->cache(_type:review_143758)],from[0],size[8],sort[<custom:\"review_type_priority\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@44ecbc5>!,<custom:\"date_reviewed\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@5123f4b8>!]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)]; nested: UncheckedExecutionException[java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)]; nested: NumberFormatException[Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)]; "
         },
         {
            "index": "blcdt.products",
            "shard": 3,
            "status": 500,
            "reason": "QueryPhaseExecutionException[[blcdt.products][3]: query[filtered(ConstantScore(cache(review_category:Game Reviews)))->cache(_type:review_143758)],from[0],size[8],sort[<custom:\"review_type_priority\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@281d24cc>!,<custom:\"date_reviewed\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@115ae1a7>!]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)]; nested: UncheckedExecutionException[java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)]; nested: NumberFormatException[Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)]; "
         },
         {
            "index": "blcdt.products",
            "shard": 4,
            "status": 500,
            "reason": "QueryPhaseExecutionException[[blcdt.products][4]: query[filtered(ConstantScore(cache(review_category:Game Reviews)))->cache(_type:review_143758)],from[0],size[8],sort[<custom:\"review_type_priority\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@41238b2a>!,<custom:\"date_reviewed\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@48593cf>!]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)]; nested: UncheckedExecutionException[java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)]; nested: NumberFormatException[Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)]; "
         },
         {
            "index": "blcdt.products",
            "shard": 0,
            "status": 500,
            "reason": "QueryPhaseExecutionException[[blcdt.products][0]: query[filtered(ConstantScore(cache(review_category:Game Reviews)))->cache(_type:review_143758)],from[0],size[8],sort[<custom:\"review_type_priority\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@1cbd767c>!,<custom:\"date_reviewed\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@5aadd5a1>!]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)]; nested: UncheckedExecutionException[java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)]; nested: NumberFormatException[Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?)]; "
         }
      ]
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 41,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "blcdt.products",
            "_type": "review_143758",
            "_id": "599606",
            "_score": null,
            "fields": {
               "score": [
                  8
               ],
               "review_type": [
                  "review"
               ],
               "review_title": [
                  "Entwined review"
               ]
            },
            "sort": [
               100,
               1403648392
            ]
         },
         ...
         {
            "_index": "blcdt.products",
            "_type": "review_143758",
            "_id": "452429",
            "_score": null,
            "fields": {
               "score": [
                  9
               ],
               "review_type": [
                  "review"
               ],
               "review_title": [
                  "Dark Souls II review"
               ]
            },
            "sort": [
               100,
               1394840094
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: what kind of data do you send to ES?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Number-Format-Exception-td1474946.html

Comment: Do you have more than one type in your index?

Comment: @DanTuffery: I did read that thread before I posted this. JohnPetrone: Yes I do define multiple types in the same index however the fields I am sorting on (review_type_priority and date_reviewed) are consistently the same data type across each type (integer and date respectively) so there should be no conflict. Ashalynd: review_type_priority gets set to any of the following intgers (0,25,50,100) and date_reviewed is set to a unix timestamp (as a long not a string) which according the ES documentation is valid.

Comment: I have confirmed that these sorting errors are preventing documents from being returned that should match the query.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out how to fix the problem but I don't know why it fixes it. By changing the datatype of 'review_type_priority' from integer to long it no longer throws the exception and now I get all the reviews I am supposed to get. Anyone care to shed light on why this field has to be a long?

Comment: Hi @sphoid. In your original example, did you create your index with mappings then immediately start indexing, or was there a delay between those two steps? How many nodes do you have?

Comment: In my case, it was caused by I accidentally trying to input a list into a field where the mapping only allow long integer

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem where I was getting failures on some shards and not on others. It turned out that I'd deleted documents, deleted mappings, added new mappings with updated data type for one field, added documents again, and my aggregation was failing to analyse the field I'd changed the mapping for.

What fixed the problem was optimising the index where the failures were occurring:

```
POST logstash-2014.08/_optimize?max_num_segments=1&wait_for_merge=false
```

(in Sense)

According to some Lucene documentation I found, a type index can be preserved even after all documents in an index are deleted, and optimising the index flushes the type index. You can see some ES documentation on optimising indexes [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-optimize.html).